# I am getting an authentication failure error while executing a oozie workflow in my cloudera VM 4.7

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am getting an authentication failure error while executing a sqoop workflow in my cloudera VM 4.7

Comment: this is my job.properties file nameNode=hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020
jobTracker=hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8021
queueName=default
examplesRoot=cloudera/Oozie
oozie.wf.application.path=$(nameNode)/user/{examplesRoot}

Comment: Instead of adding the `job.properties` into commets, add to the post itself. It will readable. Also add the exception/error you are seeing.